# Migrating from Google Datatore To Firestore in Datastore mode

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I was trying to find a step by step guide to migrate an existing project working with Datastore to the new Firebase in Datastore mode. If you do not want to wait for the [Automatic migration to Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/upgrade-to-firestore) here is my experience with the migration.

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities) page "Exporting and Importing Entities" has the steps, but I struggled a bit figuring things out. So I thought I'd share my experience.

Some notes to consider:

- Be ware of cost/time if you have a huge database!
- Yet to figure out the challenges of moving the application from Python 2.7 to Python 3 (*not entirely a datastore issue, [this doc page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#changes_to_the_app_engine_standard_environment) may help!*)!

Answer (score 0):

1. From Google Console, create a new project
2. `gcloud config set project <your-old-project-id>`
3. Create a new bucket on Google Storage *(on your old project)*
4. Export your database to the newly created bucket `gcloud datastore export gs://<your-new-bucket-name>` *(on your old project)*

   > Waiting for
   >   [projects/[your-old-project-id]/operations/AvcsdafSDFasdfI3MDQJGnRsdWFmZWQHEmVwb3J1Z
   >   S1zYm9qLW5asdfcsopEg] to finish...done.
5. From Google Console go to **IAM page** *(still on your old project)*
6. Add the new project service account account and grant "*Cloud
   Datastore Import Export Admin*" & "*Storage Admin*" permissions (***NOTE:*** for some reason when adding the "*Storage viewer*" only permission I got the below error, so I used the "**Storage Admin**" instead!)

   > "details: *[new-project-service-account]*@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to *[new-project-id]*.appspot.com."
7. Move to your new project `gcloud config set project <your-NEW-project-id>`
8. Import the data from your storage bucket `gcloud datastore import gs://<your-bucket-path>/[FILENAME].overall_export_metadata`, when done you should see a message similar to export

   > Waiting for
   >   [projects/[your-old-project-id]/operations/AaredafSDFa2otbmltZGEQCigSFmZWQHEmVwb3J1Z
   >   S1z2otbmltZGEQCigS] to finish...done.
9. *Optional*: feel free to remove the new project service account
   permission from the old project IAM page
10. If you browser to your new project Datastore page, you
     should see your migrated Entities